# R Markdown - Unable to find image at path

Tags: r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I saved an image at the path `./static/static/images/air_quality.png`. When I am adding this image to my R Markdown file, I keep getting this message `(No image at path static/images/air_quality.png)`.

Not sure what the issue is.

*Note: The path `static/images/air_quality.png` given in the R markdown file is correct.*

My question is, why is the image not being recognized?

Screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: You say `static/images/air_quality.png` in the R Markdown, but the file is in `static/static/images/air_quality.png`.  Those aren't the same.

Comment: @user2554330-static is a default folder in my root directory for storing static files. I created static/images folder in this default static folder, and all the images are stored in there. When we are adding images in R markdown, need not mention static default folder, instead just static/images/img.png should be enough. I am using Hugo + blogdown for building this site.

Comment: @user2554330-Just to mention - `![air quality](static/static/images/air_quality.png)` is also throwing the same error.

Comment: I think you'll need to simplify to a minimal reproducible example then.

Comment: I think you should you the absolute file path, just to see if you can get it atleast with that. and also try doing `/static/...` instead of just `static/...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This pandoc markdown syntax `![air quality](/static/images/air_quality.png)` is only working in `markdown` files. As I am using `R Markdown`, I have to change this code to:

````
```{r air-quality, echo=FALSE, out.width = '100%'}
knitr::include_graphics("/static/images/air_quality.png", error = FALSE)
```
````

`error = FALSE` in `include_graphics()` is important as without that argument, it throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question with the same issue, but i had some images working, and others not. There is no need for the `include_graphics()` command. **Simply right-clicking on the markdown file and selecting "reload" worked for me.**

What did not work was: `setwd("/currentPath")` and knitting the file. Knitting renders the images (telling me that the images are indeed found) but they still didn't show up on the Rmd open in RStudio.

Cause: For me this bug(?) arises when I include the file path first, and move the file to the specified folder afterwards. It seems that the location is only checked once, and thus you need to manually reload.